# Top Posts area of Profile page doesn't select the previous order/filter options between page refreshes

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

In the Top Posts section of the Profile page, when I select a filter *(All, Questions, Answers)* or order *(Votes, Newest),* the correct option is underlined and the results are filtered/reordered accordingly.

But when I refresh the page, although the results are still filtered/ordered according to my previous selections, the underlined options always revert back to "All" and "Votes".

For instance, here's my profile, ordered by "All" and "Votes" by default:

[image]

I select "Answers" and "Newest". Looks okay.

[image]

Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the page, and the selections revert to the defaults, although the previous filtering/ordering remains:

[image]

Tested on Stack Overflow, Code Review and here, so I believe it's a network-wide issue with the new Profile page (and not just one site).

Also, tested on Chrome 43.0.2357.81 m, IE 11.0.9600 and Firefox 38.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault here.

I added some code to ensure anonymous users could select non-defaults on both sets (post type filter and sorting), but neglected to check that logged in users will get their saved preferences on reload.

This is fixed and will be with you in the next build.